# Как массив разделить на два ряда?

Tags: java, android, массивы, android-studio, javafx

интересует вопрос, каким образом можно массив разделить на два ряда в конечном отображении? На данный момент массив отображается одним рядом.

```
final String[] mCitiesName ={"Васька", "Рыжик", "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Мурзик", "Рыжик",
                    "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Мурзик"};
```

---

К примеру, имеется меню, в него я закинула массив, естественно он отображается по 1 имени в столбик, необходимо из этого 1 столбика сделать 2 столбика, чтобы не было прокрутки меню.
Наглядный пример, изображение https://fastpic.co/image/hPZHnr, где Button - это массив, примерно в таком формате хотелось бы видеть массив

Comment: Что значит "два ряда в конечном отображении"? Напишите примерный результат, который вы хотите получить.

Comment: К примеру, имеется меню, в него я закинула массив, естественно он отображается по 1 имени в столбик, необходимо из этого 1 столбика сделать 2 столбика, чтобы не было прокрутки меню.
Наглядный пример, изображение https://fastpic.co/image/hPZHnr, где Button - это массив, примерно в таком формате хотелось бы видеть массив

Comment: @InnaAhtina Теперь ясно, что ваши ряды — это наши колонки. Ок. Теперь бы уточнить, что означает ваше меню (List, Action, Popup ...). Лучше если вы дадите ссылку на тот материал, который изучаете. Кстати, две колонки — это уже таблица. [сities - города, kitties - кошечки]

Comment: @oshatrk AlertDialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать свой .xml-макет и назначить его с помощью `builder.setView()`.
В макете создать два `ListView`, которые наполнить "половинками" исходного массива имен через адаптеры.

(Напрямую использовать `builder.setItems()` не удастся, так как этот метод создает свой собственный `ListView`, и добавляет его в макет самостоятельно).

Получится такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

// `activity_alert_dialog_custom_view.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

// `MyDialogFragment.java`:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private String[] catNames = {"Васька1", "Рыжик2", "Мурзик3", "Рыжик4", "Мурзик5", "Рыжик6",
            "Мурзик7", "Рыжик8", "Мурзик9", "Рыжик10", "Мурзик112"};

    private AlertDialog alertDialog;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Выберите кота");
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        final View customView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.activity_alert_dialog_custom_view, null);
        builder.setView(customView);

        List<String> items1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> items2 = new ArrayList<>();

        if (catNames != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < catNames.length; i += 2) {
                if (i + 2 <= catNames.length) {
                    // Два кота в строке:
                    items1.add(catNames[i]);
                    items2.add(catNames[i + 1]);
                } else {
                    // Остался один кот:
                    items1.add(catNames[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        ListView listView1 = customView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ListView listView2 = customView.findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // здесь тоже ..._1 !
                items2);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        listView2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                alertDialog.cancel();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        "Выбранный кот: "
                                + ((ArrayAdapter) ((ListView) parent).getAdapter()).getItem(position),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);

        alertDialog = builder.create();

        return alertDialog;
    }
}
```

// `MainActivity.java`:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void button_onClick(View view) {
        MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        myDialogFragment.show(manager, "dialog");
    }
}
```

// `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="button_onClick"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ссылки: Пока устанавливалась Android Studio и Intel HAXM, успел прочитать введение в программирование на Android 
([урок 1](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android1.php), 
[урок 2](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/android2.php)) 
и про AlertList ([урок 30](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/dialogfragment_alertdialog.php)),
а также нагуглить 
[Android Custom Layout AlertDialog Example](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-custom-layout-alertdialog-example/),
[Android Layout: width half of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20000659),
[Dynamically add elements to a listView Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/dynamically-add-elements-to-a-listview-android), [How can I set onClickListener on ArrayAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615535).

И это совсем не JavaFX...

Comment: спасибо Вам, всё прекрасно работает и всё прекрасно объяснено!

Answer (score 0):

может ТС имела ввиду типа это

```
Васька Рыжик Мурзик Рыжик Мурзик Рыжик 
Мурзик Рыжик Мурзик Рыжик Мурзик null
```

если да то один из решений может быть таким:

```
final String[] mCitiesName = {"Васька", "Рыжик", "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Мурзик", "Рыжик",
            "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Мурзик", "Рыжик", "Мурзик"};

    int count = mCitiesName.length;
    int m = (int) Math.round(count / 2d);

    String[][] mCName = new String[2][m];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mCitiesName.length; i++) {
        if (i < m) {
            mCName[0][i] = mCitiesName[i];
        } else {
            mCName[1][k++] = mCitiesName[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mCName.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mCName[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(mCName[i][j] +" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```